# Using ConfigurationManager to load config from an arbitrary location

Tags: asp.net, configuration, asp-classic

I'm developing a data access component that will be used in a website that contains a mix of classic ASP and ASP.NET pages, and need a good way to manage its configuration settings.

I'd like to use a custom `ConfigurationSection`, and for the ASP.NET pages this works great.  But when the component is called via COM interop from a classic ASP page, the component isn't running in the context of an ASP.NET request and therefore has no knowledge of web.config.

Is there a way to tell the `ConfigurationManager` to just load the configuration from an arbitrary path (e.g. `..\web.config` if my assembly is in the `/bin` folder)?  If there is then I'm thinking my component can fall back to that if the default `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` returns `null` for my custom section.

Any other approaches to this would be welcome!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912727/openmappedexeconfiguration-vs-openexeconfiguration/6599688#6599688

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default app.config at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap(strConfigPath); //Path to your config file
System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
```

Comment: How can I get _programmatically_ **strConfigPath** value for my ASP.NET _WebForms_ application hosted in ***http://sub.domain.com/virtualDir2/*** and path ***C:\Portals\App1\v2*** and _config file_ in ***C:\Portals\App1\v2\web.config*** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet: The point of the question is that strConfigPath is an _arbitrary_ location. In other words, _you_ decide what the path is, instead of relying on the framework to try to load a config file from its conventional location. I would assume [Server.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx) would give you the absolute location for any files within your solution.

Comment: Maybe `var config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/web.config");`

Comment: @Kiquenet Definitely.

Answer (score 75):

Another solution is to override the default environment configuration file path.

I find it the best solution for the of non-trivial-path configuration file load, specifically the best way to attach configuration file to dll.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", <Full_Path_To_The_Configuration_File>);
```

Example:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", @"C:\Shared\app.config");
```

More details may be found at [this blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20161222190702/http://www.testautomationguy.com/2013/01/override-default-application-config.html).

Additionally, [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6151688/503826) has an excellent solution, complete with code to refresh
the app config and an `IDisposable` object to reset it back to it's original state. With this
solution, you can keep the temporary app config scoped:

```
using(AppConfig.Change(tempFileName))
{
    // tempFileName is used for the app config during this context
}
```

Comment: This also works to load web.config files.  I use it to load a web.config instead of app.config for a task related console app. ;)

Comment: This (and the other answers here) doesn't work for me. I had added the code in the program.cs - function: Main(). My config contains an assembly version redirection (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165393/avoid-assembly-reference-problems-generally) but the redirection does not affect when the config is manually changed.

Comment: Did you use "APP_CONFIG_FILE"?

Comment: This is a very clean and easy to implement solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 42):

Ishmaeel's answer generally does work, however I found one issue, which is that using `OpenMappedMachineConfiguration` seems to lose your inherited section groups from machine.config. This means that you can access your own custom sections (which is all the OP wanted), but not the normal system sections. For example, this code will not work:

```
ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap(strConfigPath);
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
MailSettingsSectionGroup thisMail = configuration.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;  // returns null
```

Basically, if you put a watch on the `configuration.SectionGroups`, you'll see that system.net is not registered as a SectionGroup, so it's pretty much inaccessible via the normal channels.

There are two ways I found to work around this. The first, which I don't like, is to re-implement the system section groups by copying them from machine.config into your own web.config e.g.

```
<sectionGroup name="system.net" type="System.Net.Configuration.NetSectionGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
  <sectionGroup name="mailSettings" type="System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
    <section name="smtp" type="System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
```

I'm not sure the web application itself will run correctly after that, but you can access the sectionGroups correctly.

The second solution it is instead to open your web.config as an EXE configuration, which is probably closer to its intended function anyway:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { ExeConfigFilename = strConfigPath };
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
MailSettingsSectionGroup thisMail = configuration.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;  // returns valid object!
```

I daresay none of the answers provided here, neither mine or Ishmaeel's, are quite using these functions how the .NET designers intended. But, this seems to work for me.

Comment: You can also use the ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration (String) overload for the same purpose. See: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx#t2_1

Answer (score 12):

**The accepted answer is wrong!!**

It throws the following exception on accessing the AppSettings property:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.DefaultSection' to type 'System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection'.

**Here is the correct solution:**

```
System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "YourFilePath";
System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Comment: yes, this is definitely the right answer! Thanks for posting your answer.

Comment: I think System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration is even more correct but it's not available for .NET Core so in that case this answer seems to get work done.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to Ishmaeel's answer, the method `OpenMappedMachineConfiguration()` will always return a `Configuration` object. So to check to see if it loaded you should check the `HasFile` property where true means it came from a file.

Answer (score 4):

I provided the configuration values to word hosted .nET Compoent as follows.

A .NET Class Library component being called/hosted in MS Word.  To provide configuration values to my component, I created winword.exe.config in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11 folder.  You should be able to read configurations values like You do in Traditional .NET.

```
string sMsg = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WSURL"];
```

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET use WebConfigurationManager:

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/Sites/" + requestDomain + "/");
(..)
config.AppSettings.Settings["xxxx"].Value;
```

Comment: the first parameter to OpenWebConfiguration is just the path (folder). To specify a filename you need a second parameter

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "newAppConfig.config);
```

Source : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616065/Why-Where-and-How-of-NET-Configuration-Files

Answer (score 0):

Use XML processing:

```
var appPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var configPath = Path.Combine(appPath, baseFileName);;
var root = XElement.Load(configPath);

// can call root.Elements(...)
```