# How can I get ConfigurationManager to load application settings from multiple files?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration-files, configurationmanager

I'm writing applications that interoperate with a third-party application.  This application exposes an API to developers via methods in a DLL.  Some time ago, the vendor of this app started integrating their own .NET components into their program, and when they did, they decided that their components should use the `ConfigurationManager` to get settings at runtime.

What this means:  their program, `foo.exe`, calls `fooengine.dll`, and it reads its settings from `foo.exe.config`.  My program, `bar.exe`, also calls `fooengine.dll`, and it reads its settings from `bar.exe.config`.

Well, that's just plain wrong.  But how do I fix it?

The simple workaround is to replicate `foo.exe.config`'s settings in `bar.exe.config`.  That'll work, but it's *stupid*.  It means that from an administrative standpoint, a given setting has to be maintained in N different files.  That's going to fail sooner or later.

I tried putting a `configSource` attribute on the `appSettings` section in my config file.  (As it happens, I'm using the `applicationSettings` section for my settings, and they're using the `appSettings` section for theirs, so I can live with simply getting that section from a different file.)  But the `ConfigurationManager` doesn't like that:  it wants the path in `configSource` to be not only relative to but *below* my program's directory.

I can physically read their settings file into an `XmlDocument` and then set them myself.  But now I'm tightly coupling my code to their implementation; if they put out a new release that moves the settings to the `applicationSettings` section (which is where they *should* be now that it's 2009), my code will break.

Is there another way out of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I think I've found the answer, at least for my specific version of this problem.

The .NET 2.0 `ConfigurationManager` supports a `file` attribute on the `appSettings` element.  This lets you get the contents of that element from an external file.  So what I do is:

1. Cut the `appSettings` element out of `foo.exe.config` and paste it into another file in that directory called, let's say, `appSettings.xml`.
2. Add a new element to `foo.exe.config`:  `<appSettings file="appSettings.xml"/>`.
3. Add an element to `bar.exe.config`:  `<appSettings file="c:\program files\foo\appSettings.xml"/>`

This works.  But it only works because my program doesn't use `appSettings` at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could just [load their configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738/using-configurationmanager-to-load-config-from-an-arbitrary-location).

Comment: I do not believe "just" is the right word.  I can call OpenMappedMachineConfiguration to get a Configuration object.  But that doesn't update the ConfigurationManager.  And it's not trivial to get from there even to a list of name/value pairs (remember, the other app is using the old-style "appSettings" section, not the current "applicationSettings" section - GetSection returns that as a DefaultSection object).  It's quite a bit less code to just read the file into an XmlDocument.