# Visual Studio 2010 My.Settings import

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a solution with multiple projects in, and all need to share the same My.Settings, or at  least have local copies of the same set. How do I get the My.Settings from one of the projects into the others?

Comment: What do you have in there? Embedded resources, strings and such?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add it as an existing item in each project which will create a shurtcut to it. [here is my reference](http://blog.decarufel.net/2007/10/getting-access-to-settings-in-another.html) , so no need to update each project aside. 
 Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to add the settings file to your solution, then you add the existing item to your project as a link item

[How can I share Configuration Settings across multiple projects in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826812/how-can-i-share-configuration-settings-across-multiple-projects-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

The settings defined in My.settings are available to all assemblies which reference the assembly that defines those settings as long as they are public.

First ensure that "Access Modifier" is set to "Public" in the settings designer for My.settings.

Then, to access the settings, use the defining project's namespace:
{My namespace}.Properties.Settings.Default.{my setting}