# Cannot access referenced project's Settings.setting

Tags: c#, application-settings

I have added a reference of project `B` in project `A`.
When I try to access project `B` from `A`, I can use its classes and folders, but what I want is to read a string value called `ConnectionString` from its `Settings.settings` but I do cannot seem to find it. Shouldn't it be accessible via `B.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I share Configuration Settings across multiple projects in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826812/how-can-i-share-configuration-settings-across-multiple-projects-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

Create a common project so that other projects will reference to that.
Create its settings file using "add new item".
Create your variables.
In the Settings.Designer.cs class change the type of the class from internal sealed to public.

Now in every project that you want to refer this to, click on "Add > Existing item..." and choose the `Settings.designer` class file. BUT do not just click "Add" button, there is a small arrow on the button, choose "Add as link"

Clean and build your solution.
Now you should be able to refer to the settings file variable by accessing

```
[NamespaceOfOriginalProject].Settings.Default.VariableName
```