# Read Value From Web.config file In Another Directory

Tags: c#, web-services

I have two web services deployed in the same directory. I am trying to read a value from `Web.config` file of one of the web services from the other. Is this possible?

i tried this but its not working:

```
  protected static string GetApplicationSettings(string sKey)
        {
            string sValue = null;
            System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig =
               System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/WebServiceTest/WebServiceTest/web.config");
            //check if the AppSettings section has items
            if (rootWebConfig.AppSettings.Settings.Count > 0)
            {
                sValue = rootWebConfig.AppSettings.Settings[sKey].Value;
            }
            return sValue;
        }
```

Comment: probably you're looking at the wrong location. Try giving the full path..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap(file); //Path to your config file
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
string value = configuration.AppSettings.Settings["sKey"].Value;
```

Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361913/single-app-config-multi-project-c-sharp)