# Relative path to solution directory in App.config

Tags: c#, app-config, appsettings

I have a solution with multiple projects, I have common settings int he AppSettings in the app.config and web.config that are used in may of the projects.

I created AppSetting.config in my $SolutionDir\Solution Items folder.

In every app.config or web.config that needs these settings, I want to do soemthign like this:

```
<appSettings file="$SolutionDir\Solution Items\App.config"/>
```

is there anything equivalent to this Macro that works inside App.config ?

Comment: Yes, You do it in Machine Config. If other applications do not have dependency

Comment: Possible duplicate of [single app.config multi-project c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361913/single-app-config-multi-project-c-sharp)

Comment: Dont want to do it in machine config, and not the dup is not the same as mince