# How to integrate multiple class library project in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a solution in .NET with 4 class library projects and each project has its own functionality and own App.Config file. All these class library projects are created using .Net Framework 4.6.

Now the client wants to utilize these 4 project's functionalities in their WPF application. Here my problem  is, to utilize all the 4 projects, user needs to configure all 4 App.Config files separately. But the client expects a solution with a single Config file to configure all these 4 projects.

So now I want to integrate all these project by creating one more project in the same solution which should act as a Entry or Startup project. And also the final solution should have only one common Config file.

**One very important point here is, it should not be a web based project type.**

Can someone tell me the .Net project type which I need to use to create an entry project?

Comment: usually you have a config-file per **app**, not per assembly.

Comment: "Now the client wants to utilize these 4 project's functionalities in their WPF application" - so entry project should be WPF proj which should contains single app config with "merged" values for other libs. Depends how your libs reading values from configs

Comment: it's like you have 1 project and installing 4 new nuget-packages to it

Comment: @HimBromBeere - I couldn't create common config file in my solution, hence created config-file per assembly. Can you please tell me how to create a common config-file. That is the main issue for me. To solve this issue only I am trying to create new entry project.

Comment: @demo - I want to make my application as multiple assembly with single config file that is my main ask.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [single app.config multi-project c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361913/single-app-config-multi-project-c-sharp)

Comment: @demo - Will this approach work at runtime(creating a config file as a link)? Because all my 4 projects are class library projects.