# ASP.NET Core can't take app.setting in MSTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mstest

I have `appsettings.json` in my ASP.NET Core Web API with key and value and it works perfectly:

[image]

But, when I want use `ConfigurationManager` to get value in MSTEST's method, I always get NULL:

[image]

Please, help me, how can I get the correct value?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your WebApi and Tests are two different projects. The `App.config` file is set up for the WebApi.

You can look into this answer about setting up one config file for multiple projects:
[Single App config multi project C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361913/single-app-config-multi-project-c-sharp)