# App.config file not getting read from non-startup project

Tags: c#, configuration, config, app-config

In my solution I have two projects, one which is set to the startup project, the other not.  I have added an App.config file to the start-up project.

The App.config file works in the project which is the startup project, but I cannot read the App.config from the other project, the data is coming back as null.

If I want my non start-up project to access the App.config file in the start-up project, what settings do I need to change?

I am using the following code to access the file.  String testrail is coming back as null when running from the non start-up project.

```
public string testrail;
testrail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testrail"];
```

My App.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="testrail" value="True"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [single app.config multi-project c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361913/single-app-config-multi-project-c-sharp)

Comment: @horotab I tried the shared project solution but it didn't work.  Still returning with null.

Comment: can you still access it from the startup project?