# How to parse web.config file in c#

Tags: c#, web-config

I have web.config file from some application. It is located in some random location. I have to parse this web.config file (get all keys names and values). I tried to use ConfigurationManager class in order to get those data however, it throws exception when I try to get some Sections (Configuration->GetSection('section name')). It throws exception because I do not have dll that this section points to (because I have only web.config not whole application). It seems that GetSection method check underlying dll in order to get more info, but I just need value (name of dll).

What can I do, to turn off this mechanism, do you know other simple solutions to get it done ?

Comment: have a look at this post. seems this is what your are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738/using-configurationmanager-to-load-config-from-an-arbitrary-location

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are just going to have to use [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) or [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) (3.5) to parse the file.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to read the text, and not do any `web.config`-specific processing, use the fact that a `.config` file is XML, and use your favourite usual way of reading and parsing XML.

Answer (score 2):

Web.Config files are just XML and an be read using a number of .Net XML objects. Below are a couple of methods.

Tutorial on reading an XML file using XmlTextReader http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548

Tutorial on reading an XML file using LinqToSQL http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1524