# .NET settings files in class library projects

Tags: c#, wpf, application-settings

I want to use a .NET settings file in an external dll library. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246201/Settings-in-an-assembly-configuration-file) explains exactly what I am trying to do.

```
partial class LastState
{
    public LastState() : base(new ConfigurationFileApplicationSettings("LastState.config", typeof(LastState))) { }
}
```

Unfortunately, using this implementation, it is not possible to save settings back to the config file. If I try to use `Save()`, SetPropertyValues throws a NotSupportedException. Is there any way to save a .NET settings file from an external dll library?

Answer (score 3):

I would use [custom configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505566/loading-custom-configuration-files).

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"d:\test\justAConfigFile.config.whateverYouLikeExtension";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel)
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912727/openmappedexeconfiguration-vs-openexeconfiguration) for more détails.

You can save with

```
config.AppSettings.Settings["YourThing"].Value = "New Value";
config.Save();
```