# Change the store location of application setting file

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using ConfigurationManager to load config from an arbitrary location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738/using-configurationmanager-to-load-config-from-an-arbitrary-location)

I'm using Setting File to store my application's settings. The setting file will be stored in %AppData%\CompanyName\user.config. How to change store location? Example: I want to save this config file in %AppData%\CompanyName\ApplicationName\Version\user.config

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might decide to use .NET per-user(roaming) settings:

```
Configuration roamingConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming);
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx), you cannot use OpenExeConfiguration because it accepts **path to the executable**, not the path to configuration file. You should use [OpenMappedExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration.aspx) with ExeConfigurationFileMap structure that contains full path to configuration file.