# Can't access another project's app.config file

Tags: c#, app-config

Currently I have 2 apps, App1 and App2.

App1 has an app.config file where I store the string `InstallDir`. I can access this from App1 fine using `Properties.Settings.Default.InstallDir`. Which works great, but I need to be able to access this from App2.

I changed the accessibility from `Internal` to `Public` in VS. When I try to access it from App2 I add a reference to App1 and use `using App1;` and `App1.Properties.Settings.Default.InstallDir` but it justs returns nothing. It doesn't throw an exception, it just returns a blank string.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a comment, why not put this information in a third place both apps can access like a separate config file or a database? The kind of config you are dicussing feels more volatile than what usually goes in app.config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every application has its own app.config file where it reads configuration from at runtime. You have referenced App1 in App2 which allows you to access the `App1.Properties.Settings.Default.InstallDir` variable but at runtime since there's no corresponding value in the app.config of App2 it returns null.

Comment: Thanks. I'm slightly confused though. So I can't access the value in App1 from App2 without having the same value in App2's config file?

Comment: @BaliC, yes, that's what I am saying.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access some (I presume) *shared* configuration options between 2 projects, create wrapper for the config on the first one (let's say a `static` class) and use it from your second project.

Comment: Thanks. I need to retain the value of the InstallDir after the app is closed which is why I use the config file. Unless the variable in the static class is somehow retained after the app has closed?

Comment: @Bali: how that APP can be "closed" ? Do you refer an EXE project?

Comment: Yeah, I refer to the exe project, so when the application is closed, I need to save the value, like I can save it to the config file, so when it opens I can access it again.

Comment: Yes but that is a duty of that application that closing (to save its Config data). You can access that information in other project still after closing.

Answer (score 0):

You can only write your own code to switch reading another config file, even you add App2 as a reference it would not magically give you access, read it as a normal file or use ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your application will only have loaded one configuration file, if you want to read values from the other file you will need to explicitly load it.

look at [Using ConfigurationManager to load config from an arbitrary location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738/using-configurationmanager-to-load-config-from-an-arbitrary-location) for some help with this.

Comment: Currently my app.config is compiled with the exe, so it isn't compiled as a separate file, I presume I wouldn't be able to use this until it is a separate file?