# Making a constant available to a T4 template and normal source code

Tags: .net, t4

I have a T4 template that needs to access an integer constant so it can generate the correct file structure at **build time**. The generated file is *not* source code and so cannot access this constant at run time. This constant should also be available to my C# source code at **runtime**.

Ideally I would like only one place to set the value of this integer constant to avoid maintenance problems in the future where colleagues may set the value in the C# code one place and forget to set it in the template.

Where can I place this constant so I only have to edit it in one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put it in the `app.config`/`web.config` file, and read that in the T4 template, and the source code.

Comment: The source is in a library not an application.

Comment: Ok I see it is not a problem to add a config file to a library but how to read the config file from the T4 template as it is being hosted not by the application but by visual studio.

Comment: See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738/using-configurationmanager-to-load-config-from-an-arbitrary-location