# Using client endpoints from app.config file

Tags: asp.net, wcf-client

.net 4.0

I have two web projects using their own `web.config` file and using the same endpoints to call the same WCF web service.

Both use a common project (dll) which has an `app.config` file. I would like to move the endpoint info into that config file - is this possible? I want endpoint information

```
<client>  
    <endpoint/> 
<client/>
```

to be shared by both web app from common place?

`Web.config` file binding info omitted here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings/>          
      <client configSource="client.config">
   <system.serviceModel/>
</configuration>
```

`client.config` file within common project

```
 <client>
      <endpoint
        name="endpoint1"
        address="http://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IHello"
        behaviorConfiguration="IHello_Behavior"
        contract="IHello"/ >
```

Apology for typo two things i changed 
1. client.config had a   element took that out.
2. within  the build properties of project added COPY "$(TargetDir)*.config" "$(ProjectDir)"

Just to mention both in web.config (configSource)& client.config  VStudio shouts design time but runs fine?

Comment: I have worked in such a kind of scenario and I suggest it is not doable. Let the comments flood in and will have more information.

Comment: What is that odd looking `</endpoint>` in the middle of your `web.config / <system.serviceModel>` - please remove that. Also: the `<client>` in your `web.config` as well as the `<endpoint>` tag in your `client.config` aren't properly closed ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share parts of the WCF config by "outsourcing" it:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client configSource="client.config" />
    .....
</system.serviceModel>
```

and then have this content in your `client.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<client>
    <endpoint name="ABC"
        address="http://......."
        binding="......."
        contract="......" />
</client>
```

You cannot put stuff into the `app.config` of a common assembly, since those config files will not be used / looked at by the .NET framework. You need to put your info into the **main** config file of the app or web site (`web.config`) - but you *can* "externalize" certain sections into separate, external files and sharing them like that.

Comment: I think you have explained how we can have different configs for different sections. But here the question is adding endpoints in app.config.

Comment: @CodeSpread: you can have this `<client configSource="client.config" />` in your `app.config` (or `web.config`) and put the actual client configuration into an external file, that can be shared amongst multiple projects....

Comment: you are correct. but can you please answer me about the original question "adding endpoints in app.config" in a different project when you have web.config available.

Comment: @CodeSpread: as I'm already mentioning in my answer - you cannot add configuration to a **class-library `app.config`** since .NET doesn't look at those - that's absolutely correct

Comment: Ok. Actually i have already answered the same in the very first comment.Then after seeing your answer, I thought you are suggesting a way to do that.--codespread

Comment: @ marc_s : Alright so are you saying i can create client.config in the common project?

Comment: @Gauls: yes - you just need to make sure all projects that need it have a current copy of it sitting next to their own `web.config` (e.g. by copying around the config file, or by establishing "symbol links" with that file - whatever).

Comment: @marc_s : I created client.config in common proj and rest of bit is in web.config <client configSource="client.config" />. Also added client.config within each project as "add as link". when i run web app it errors saying "unable to open configSource file client.config "??

Comment: @Gauls: do you **copy** the `client.config` to your **output directory** where the `web.config` exists at runtime??

Comment: @marc_s: I have selected to copy to output directory for common and web projects still same error :(

Comment: @Gauls: can you upload your `web.config` and a screenshot of your web application's main directory (where `web.config` is located)? Here inside your question, or to some other site where we can go have a look at it ....

Answer (score 0):

I have worked in such a kind of scenario and I suggest it is not doable.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a custom ChannelFactory class and then specify the client.config path by injection or by default rules.

Here is how to write the custom ChannelFactory that accepts a custom configuration path:
http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/10/19/loading-the-wcf-configuration-from-different-files-on-the-client-side.aspx

I used `this.GetType.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule.Name + ".config"` to dynamically get a default config file that matches the name of my shared library.

You can have both of your web apps instantiate the custom ChannelFactory with the configuration path or you can add a layer of abstraction in your common library that interacts with the web service and then your web apps use the new abstract object instead of a direct dependency on the web service. This works great when you need to accommodate updates to the web service without disturbing your web apps.

More details in this SO Answer: [Using ConfigurationManager to load config from an arbitrary location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738/using-configurationmanager-to-load-config-from-an-arbitrary-location/14246260#14246260)