# Get value from inherited web config within my project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, web-config

I have a Web API project, that has 3 controller projects eg:

```
ControllerProject1

ControllerProject2

ControllerProject3
```

The hierarchy is as follows:

`ControllerProject3` and `ControllerProject2` cannot access each other but can both access `ControllerProject1`

each project has its own Web.config.

I then add a setting to the config of `ControllerProject1` as follows:

```
<add key="SettingName" value="SettingValue"/>
```

In `ControllerProject1` I obtain values from the Web.Config as follows:

```
var setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SettingName"];
```

However, my issue is that I now want to obtain the value from `ControllerProject1` Web.Config, through a method contained in `ControllerProject2` or `ControllerProject3`

I know I can add settings to all 3 configs, but my question is, is it possible to do this, and if so how can I do this?

EDIT:

This question [Accessing Web.config from another Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838836/accessing-web-config-from-another-project) does this by declaring the path to this  file, but I would prefer to do this by referencing the project rather than the path to the config file

Comment: You can use a static class in the project that has the web.config file and expose the value of the web.config in an internal property