# Unable to use WebConfigurationManager for WCF project

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to write a WCF service that links another project's App.config file.
This is a .net 3.5 project and when I try to use:

```
SystemsConfigurationHandler systemsSection = Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("thirdPartySystemsSection") as SystemsConfigurationHandler;
```

But it still doesn't know what WebConfigurationManager is.

[image: Line of code having the problem.]

"The type or namespace name 'Configuration' doesnt not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'"

yet looking in the object browser its clearly there. How can I fix this?

[image: System.Web.Configuration shows WebConfigurationManager there.]

Also I am trying to browse a linked App.config file from another project to give an idea of what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using [WebConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)?

> Using WebConfigurationManager is the preferred way to work with
>   configuration files related to **Web applications**. For client
>   applications, use the ConfigurationManager class.

Note that you also can't just access another project's .config file. You could [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738/using-configurationmanager-to-load-config-from-an-arbitrary-location).

Comment: I tried using ConfigurationManager but it only shows my connection strings and not everything from the App.config file when I explore that code. and I linked the App.config file to my project. so its basically just a copy or at least that is what I had believed.