# C# Opening a configuration file from an arbitrary location

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

At:

[Using ConfigurationManager to load config from an arbitrary location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738/using-configurationmanager-to-load-config-from-an-arbitrary-location)
I found what seems like a solution. A project I'm working on uses an appSettings.config file location on the network. BUT when I tried to use the referenced code:

```
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap("Z:\Settings\appSettings.config"); //Path to your config file

 System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
```

So far so good. The appSettings.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Environment" value="Development" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

BUT then I get to this following line:

```
var settings = configuration.AppSettings.Settings;
```

or anything using it, like Settings.Count, I get an Invalid Cast Exception. Basically, how would I get the value for "Environment" from this?

Comment: `var environment = configuration.AppSettings["Environment"]`

Comment: Looks like the `appSettings` tag is not mapped to an `AppSettingsSection` object, but rather to `DefaultSection`. Not sure why though, I'll get back to you if I come to any conclusions.

Answer (score 6):

I found this works:

```
System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();

fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"Z:\appSettings.config"; //Path to your config file

System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None); // OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
return configuration.AppSettings.Settings["Environment"].Value;
```

This works without error.

Comment: Thanks :) Tried and failed a ton of other solutions.